# Dual Mouse Config reverse button mapping

Tags: 19.04, wayland, libinput

I am trying to figure out how to set my left mouse to Left-handed and my right mouse to right handed.  There are so many layers here it is quite tricky these days.  I am attempting to use Wayland instead of X but would be fine to go back.  Looks like I need a libinput stanza in something like this /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf.  Thought that would be global I suspect. Which would be ok.  It would seem nicer to make it for just my account but the global solution would work.

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Kensington Expert Mouse"
    Driver "libinput"
    Left-handed "on"
EndSection
```

Then leave the right mouse stock and set the control panel to right handed?  Is the search really on the name string?  Can I search on the device path?  Kinda sucks they didn't use /dev/input/mouse0||mouse1 cause /dev/input/event2 is so much better.  Oddly

```
xophere@xophere-ws:~$ xinput 
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:16                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:16              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:16                      id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

xinput get-button-map for 4, 6, and 7 show what is expected. Using it to swap them changes the output but not the behavior of the devices.

Below are my notes on my two Expert Mouses. They are slightly different models but physically the same.  I am happy to chase this down I just can't figure out where the docs are.  It seems like libinput is too low level to describe the situation for an end user and Ubuntu hasn't got any docs that explain how to approach this.  Lots of older stuff around that doesn't seem to work for me in wayland.  My case is pretty easy as I am not trying anything too fancy.  I just want the button flip for one device and not the other.  Also once I figure it out where would I submit the information I have learned for others to follow?

```
expert mouse
lower left 1
upper left 2
lower right 3
upper righ 8
right turn 5
left turn 4

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
3 8 1 5 4 6 7 2 9 10


Left Mouse outter mouse port
I: Bus=0003 Vendor=047d Product=1020 Version=0111
N: Name="Kensington Expert Mouse"
P: Phys=usb-0000:03:00.0-11.1.2/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:03:00.0/usb1/1-11/1-11.1/1-11.1.2/1-11.1.2:1.0/0003:047D:1020.0002/input/input3
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event2 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=17
B: KEY=1f0000 0 0 0 0
B: REL=903
B: MSC=10

Device:           Kensington Expert Mouse
Kernel:           /dev/input/event2
Group:            3
Seat:             seat0, default
Capabilities:     pointer 
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      disabled
Nat.scrolling:    disabled
Middle emulation: disabled
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   button
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Accel profiles:   flat *adaptive
Rotation:         0.0

Right Mouse inner USB port
I: Bus=0003 Vendor=047d Product=1020 Version=0110
N: Name="Kensington      Kensington Expert Mouse"
P: Phys=usb-0000:03:00.0-11.1.4/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:03:00.0/usb1/1-11/1-11.1/1-11.1.4/1-11.1.4:1.0/0003:047D:1020.0006/input/input7
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse1 event6 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=17
B: KEY=f0000 0 0 0 0
B: REL=903
B: MSC=10

Device:           Kensington      Kensington Expert Mouse
Kernel:           /dev/input/event6
Group:            3
Seat:             seat0, default
Capabilities:     pointer 
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      disabled
Nat.scrolling:    disabled
Middle emulation: disabled
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   button
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Accel profiles:   flat *adaptive
Rotation:         0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the same problem but this my help.
I was looking for a way to configure my extra mouse buttons
sadly btnx is no longer in the repos for debian/ubuntu
so instead i had to download, install and build from source:

1. https://github.com/cdobrich/btnx-config
2. https://github.com/cdobrich/btnx

this enables me to configure each individual button on different ponting devices attached to the same computer
my guess is that you can configure the buttons the way you want this way